# Html charset for German char not working

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I have set in my html page:

```
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

but still I am not able to see the special chars and instead there is replacement.

I have set:

```
define("MENU_TEXT_LINK3", "Medica Ärztebedarf");
```

and as you can see in the top right menu [site](http://medica.mastertools.net/) it is not shown.

Comment: this is UTF-8 related

Comment: even if i set UTF-8 is not working

Comment: Does this involve a database? Plus, UTF-8 goes further than just setting meta tags; so does the file(s)'s encoding.

Comment: Sometimes, even if you confgure the charset of your content, your file may have other charset. You can change that using eclipse or notepad++.

Comment: in this case is not the db because that string is defined in the code and is not from the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta charset in html page was set fine. The problem was that the packet header was not set fine, so I changed basic configuraation charset in codeigniter and it works

Comment: If you are talking about the HTTP response header, yes, browsers interpret that as an override of the HTML declared charset. Ideally, you would trust the declared charset for HTML files and never override for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try change the file charset encoding or use html entities to avoid that.